# MongoDB : Update an object in a document's array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

I have the following collection :

```
{
    "_id": "5fcde7d433d4303b242a8048",
    "model": "CL",
    "type": "ARCHCOMP",
    "idProject": "5fcde7d133d4303b242a8041",
    "qtts": [
        {
            "component": "5fca0fbac09bc7bca5628256",
            "qttEU": 5,
            "qttUSA": 10,
            "qttAS": 20
        },
        {
            "component": "5fca136ec09bc7bca5628257",
            "qttEU": 10,
            "qttUSA": 15,
            "qttAS": 25
        }
    ]
},
{
    Other documents...
}
```

I need to update the fields 'qttEU', 'qttUSA' and 'qttAS' of a specific component (which id is given) of a specific document (which id is given too) but I can't make it works...

Here is what I have tried :

```
Document.updateOne({ _id: "5fcde7d433d4303b242a8048", "qtts.component": "5fca0fbac09bc7bca5628256" },
                   { $set: {"qtts.$.qttEU": 11, "qtts.$.qttUSA": 12, "qtts.$.qttAS": 13 }})
```

I get a response that the document have been successfully updated but when I check the db the values are not updated...
If I query the db with that :

```
Document.findOne({ _id: "5fcde7d433d4303b242a8048", "qtts.component": "5fca0fbac09bc7bca5628256" })
```

it returns me the good document. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it.
Firstly, I was doing wrong my query. As AartiVerma answered me, I have to do

```
Document.updateOne({ _id: "5fcde7d433d4303b242a8048", qtts:{ $elemMatch: { component: "5fca0fbac09bc7bca5628256"}}},
                   { $set: {"qtts.$.qttEU": 11, "qtts.$.qttUSA": 12, "qtts.$.qttAS": 13 }})
```

Instead of

```
Document.updateOne({ _id: "5fcde7d433d4303b242a8048", "qtts.component": "5fca0fbac09bc7bca5628256" },
                   { $set: {"qtts.$.qttEU": 11, "qtts.$.qttUSA": 12, "qtts.$.qttAS": 13 }})
```

Secondly, my mongoose schema was wrong. It was like :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const sheetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    model: { type: String },
    type: { type: String },
    qtts: { type: Array },
    idProject: { type: String }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Sheet', sheetSchema);
```

Instead of :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const sheetSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    model: { type: String },
    type: { type: String },
    qtts: [{ component: String, qttEU: Number, qttUSA: Number, qttAS: Number }],
    idProject: { type: String }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Sheet', sheetSchema);
```

Note the difference for **qtts**

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. qtts is an array so you should use $elemMatch for match values in array:-

```
Document.updateOne({ _id: "5fcde7d433d4303b242a8048", qtts:{ $elemMatch: { component: "5fca0fbac09bc7bca5628256"}}},
               { $set: {"qtts.$.qttEU": 11, "qtts.$.qttUSA": 12, "qtts.$.qttAS": 13 }})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you gave me half the solution of the problem :)